# Bootstrap Table - To change the background color row

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I need to change the background color row, but not working well.

This is the js code:

```
$("#table-results").bootstrapTable({ 
    method: 'get',
    url: '/json/data-results.json',
    columns: [{
        field: 'type'   
    }, {
        field: 'customer_name'
    }, {
        field: 'address'
    }, {
        field: 'img',
        align: 'center'

    }],
    onLoadSuccess: function(res) {
        $("#table-results").on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
            $($element).addClass('danger');
        });
    }   
});
```

Other way (but not working)

```
$("#table-results").bootstrapTable({ 
    columns: [{
        field: 'type'   
    }, {
        field: 'customer_name'
    }, {
        field: 'address'
    }, {
        field: 'img',
        align: 'center'

    }],
    onClickRow: function (row, $element) {
        $($element).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        //$($element).addClass('danger');
    }
});
```

This is the css code:

```
.danger {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Which is the problem?, thanks,

Comment: mate add some fiddle or more code, it is vague representation of problem

Comment: I am using the next event onClickRow of bootstrap-table but not working, the argument $element  is the tr element, but when i try to add a class for to change background color row not working

Comment: let me know if your code is online

Comment: do you have some html as well?